# Simple Discrete Math Probability Question - Uniform and Independent

Tags: probability

Kyle, Kenny, Cartman, and Stan have 210 otters each. In order to keep
track of them all, each one numbers their otters from 1 to 210, and each otter receives a collar
with its number on it. Unfortunately, otter collars do not come in many varieties, so all of Kyle
and Kenny’s otters have green collars, and all of Cartman and Stan’s otters have yellow collars.
The otters are released into two large pools. So that the owners can tell them apart, Kyle and
Cartman’s otters are in one pool and Kenny and Stan’s otters are in the other. We now pick
one otter from each pool independently and uniformly at random:

(a) Given that at least one of the otters picked has a green collar, what is the probability that both otters chosen have green collars?

(b) Given that at least one of the otters has a green collar and is numbered 13, what is the probability that both otters have a green collar?

It seems kind of simple but I just don't know where to start.

For part a) Since I have 420 otters in each pool, and 210 in each pool have green collars, would it simply just be $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$?

I have no idea how to do part b. So any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: No.  You've just computed the probability that both have green collars, without using the information that one of them has a green collar.  This is a conditional probability; you need Bayes' rule.

Answer (score 1):

Note $G_1$ the outcome "the first otter has a green collar", $G_2$ the outcome "the second otter has a green collar".

You have to find $\mathbb P_{G_1}(G_2)$. If the first otter had a green collar, then remains $419$ otters in the pool, $209$ of which having a green collar.

So : $\mathbb P_{G_1}(G_2)=\frac{209}{419}$.

Note that the color of the collar and the number are independent issues, so the knowledge of the number doesn't change the conditional probability (for question (b)).